# Django Field 'id' expected a number but got '.....'. getting this error if forward slash missing from end of url

Tags: django

I am facing this error after added delete function in my views. if forward slash missing from end of any url like this `"http://127.0.0.1:8000/blog"` then I am getting this error  `Field 'id' expected a number but got 'blog'.` If I type `http://127.0.0.1:8000/blog/` then it taking to me blog page. For example I am trying to access my admin page like this `http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin` then it will give me same error `Field 'id' expected a number but got 'admin'.`  This error happening for my all url. After adding this delete function in my views  I am getting this error:

```
def DeleteNotificaton(request,noti_id):
    user= request.user

    if user.is_authenticated:
        author = Blog.objects.filter(author=user)
        if not author:
            Notifications.objects.filter(id=noti_id,receiver=user).delete()
            Notifications.objects.filter(id=noti_id,sender=user).delete()
            messages.add_message(request, messages.INFO, 'Notification deleted sucessfully.')
            return redirect('notifications:notify')
        if author:
         Notifications.objects.filter(id=noti_id,receiver=user).delete()
         messages.add_message(request, messages.INFO, 'Notification deleted sucessfully.')
         return redirect('notifications:notify_author')
    
    return redirect('http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/')
```

how to solve this any idea??

my **urls.py**

```
from django.urls import path,include
from notifications import views
from .views import *
app_name = 'notifications'
urlpatterns = [
  
    path('notifications/',views.ShowNOtifications,name='notify'),
    path('author-notifications/',views.ShowAuthorNOtifications,name='notify_author'),
    path('<noti_id>',views.DeleteNotificaton, name='delete-noti'),
     
   
 
]
```

console error:

```
ValueError: Field 'id' expected a number but got 'blog'.
[25/Jul/2021 23:51:21] "GET /blog HTTP/1.1" 500 134098
```

Comment: Share your urls.py. You likely need to reorder these, or make these more specific.

Comment: Willem Van Onsem  I updated my question and added urls.py of my app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the result of defining the URLs that way. You first match with `<noti_id>` and since `noti_id` is an arbitrary string, it thus matches with `/blog` and will call the `DeleteNotificaton` view bith `'blog'` as `noti_id`.

You can make your patterns more restrictive such that `pk` only accepts numbers by working with the `<int:…>` path converter:

```
from django.urls import path,include
from notifications import views
from .views import *

app_name = 'notifications'

urlpatterns = [  
    path('notifications/',views.ShowNOtifications,name='notify'),
    path('author-notifications/',views.ShowAuthorNOtifications,name='notify_author'),
    path('<int:noti_id>',views.DeleteNotificaton, name='delete-noti'),
]
```

---

> **Note**: [*Section 9* of the *HTTP protocol*](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html#sec9.1.1)
> specifies that requests like GET and HEAD should *not* have side-effects, so you
> should not change entities with such requests. Normally POST, PUT, PATCH, and
> DELETE requests are used for this. In that case you make a small `<form>` that
> will trigger a POST request, or you use some AJAX calls.

Comment: Willem Van Onsem Thanks for your help.  it was happening for not adding `int`. So we should define `int` or `slug` in our url for delete or update objects???

Comment: @boyenec: that is often a very good idea, to make the patterns as restrictive as possible such that these do not "fire" a view that was not the intended use case.